# select listview index in c# webBrowser progmatically

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

Ho All,

i am writing a C# code which will open page and then select a item from list view.

this is my code.

```
    webBrowser.Document.GetElementById("x:446594328.7:mkr:List:nw:1").SetAttribute("SelectedIndex", "2";
```

but is is not selecting items from list.

list is somewhat like

```
    <ul id="x:446594328.7:mkr:List:nw:1" class="igdd_DropDownList " nw="1" mkr="List">
    <li class="igdd_ListItem " id="x:446594328.8:adr:0" adr="0"><a href="javascript:void(0)"></a></li>
  <li class="igdd_ListItem " id="x:446594328.9:adr:1" adr="1"><a href="javascript:void(0)">xyz</a></li>
    <li class="igdd_ListItem " id="x:446594328.10:adr:2" adr="2"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Pqr</a></li> 
    </ul>
```

Comment: Those elements have no ID at all.

Comment: i have given just an example

Comment: There must be some Javascript (this is just a guess as you don't provide the full code) which emulates a dropdown, so you need to check how that script "select" an element.

Comment: i had updated the question with original code please have a look :)